# spit string and set them to map as a marker

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dictionary, bing, marker

i am try to create marker on map.
i am use bing Map
i have two string with comma separate.
in two different variable.

```
var Region = "Pune,Kolkata";
var Activity = "Cricket,One Day";
```

i am try this java-Script ajax:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/MapControl/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.3c">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Region = 'Pune,Kolkata';
    var cntry_code= 'IN';
    var Activity = "Cricket,One Day"
    var map = null;
    function GetMap() {
        map = new VEMap('myMap');            
        map.LoadMap();
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var array_region = Region.split(',');
            var array_activtiy= Activity.split(',');
            for(var item_region in array_region)
            for (var item_activity in array_activtiy)
            {
            $.ajax({
              url: "http://services.gisgraphy.com//geocoding/geocode?address="+array_region[item_region]+"&country="+cntry_code+"&format=json",
             async: false,
              dataType:'jsonp',
              success: function(data){
                    lat = data.result[0].lat;
                    lng = data.result[0].lng;
                alert(lat);
                alert(lng);
                map.LoadMap(new VELatLong(lat,lng));
                var pinpoint = map.GetCenter();      
                shape = new VEShape(VEShapeType.Pushpin, pinpoint);
                shape.SetTitle("Activity Name:- ");
                shape.SetDescription(array_activtiy[item_activity]+","+array_region[item_region]);
                map.AddShape(shape);
                }
                });
                                alert(array_region[item_region]);

    }
        });
        }
</script>
    </head>
    <body onload="GetMap();">
    <div style="width:630px; background-color: #E0E0E0; height: 500px; border: 1px solid black">
        <div id='myMap' style="position:relative; width:600px; height:400px; margin-left:15px"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

with this try to split string with comma.
and pass this to ajax url.
and got the lat and lng.
use this lat and lng.
set those place there Activity.
its work fine.
just little problem its add last place and last activity as a marker.
i think problem in my for loop.
please some one check it out my this query.
thanks.

Comment: are you getting the success response from ajax?

Comment: @anoooooooooooooooop yes i got..

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `for(var item_region in array_region)` construct with Arrays. Replace that line with something like:

```
for (var item_region, i = 0; i < array_region.length; i++)
  item_region = array_region[i];
```

You will need to do a similar change on the following line - left as an exercise